# Removing endline character

Tags: c, unix, named-pipes

So I'm trying to read from a fifo-file (a named pipe basically), but when I'm doing a string comparison, using `strcmp()` it is not giving expected output.

I tried getting the length of the message using strlen(), and explicitly setting the character as '\0', but still it is not working.

```
ret_val = read(fd,buff,BUFFSIZE);
// where buff is the character array reading from the fd of the fifo-file.
// and buffsize has been defined as 32
ret_val = 1;
str_len = strlen(buff);  
buff[str_len] = '\0';  
ret_val = strcmp(buff,"bye");  
if(!ret_val)  {
    printf("\nProgram is terminating . . .");  
}
```

Comment: `read` does not read *lines* so beforehand you cannot know beforehand, given large enough buffer, if you'll get one line, 2 characters, 1.3247 lines or 752 lines in the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

```
str_len = strlen(buff);  
buff[str_len] = '\0';
```

This isn't right. `read()` doesn't null terminate `buff`. So you can't call `strlen()` on it. If it did, you wouldn't have to do this at all.

Use the return value of `read()` and null terminate:

```
    ret_val = read(fd,buff,BUFFSIZE);

    if (ret_val != -1)
    {
        buff[ret_val] = '\0';
    }
```

Then you can do `strcmp`.

You also need to take care of another edge case: If `read()` returns `BUFFSIZE` then there's no space to add the null terminator. So you either to have truncate `buff` (lose the last char) or pass `BUFFSIZE - 1` to buf.

Alternatively, you can use `memcmp`. This would avoid the need to null terminate as well.

Answer (score 0):

Even `strlen` to work you need `char *` to be `null` terminated. As of now you are invoking undefined behavior by passing non `null` terminated string to `strlen`.

Thus, replace

```
str_len = strlen(buff);  
buff[str_len] = '\0';
```

by

```
   buff[ret_val ] = '\0';
```

Add boundary condition check for `ret_val` before using it as index.

---

Also remove the below line

```
ret_val = 1;
```

As it is overwriting the `read` return value.